# Do I need an indefinite article, talking about exposition in literature?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

For example:

> It's only (an) exposition, but I already love the story.

Comment: Do you mean something like "_I'm still in the exposition stage of the story_ (i.e. where the author establishes the setting and introduces the main characters), _but I already love the story_"?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I wanted to replace the word "beginning" with "exposition" to make the sentence sound more interesting. But I got confused whether I should put an indefinite article here.

Comment: Then you need the definite article. But _it's only the exposition_ does not clearly convey the fact that you are still/only at that stage of the story.

Comment: What does "exposition" mean here? Please expand on your question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/exposition) advises that count and non-count usages of *exposition* (in the explanation, not the exhibition, sense) are in use:

> **exposition** [noun] [countable, uncountable] (formal): a full explanation of a theory, plan, etc.
>
> - *a clear and detailed exposition of their legal position*

However, the definition they give applies to the count usage, shown in the example.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exposition) gives an example of the non-count usage:

> - *He is masterly in absorbing information and masterful in organizing it—skeptical of fashion, clear in exposition, fluent in communication,
>   unremittingly scholarly*. — Felipe Fernandez-Armesto, New York Times
>   Book Review, 11 June 2000

And a typical example is given in this article from [[Grace Bible Church Plantation](https://www.gbcplantation.org/page/philosophy-of-preaching#:%7E:text=Biblical%20exposition%20simply%20means%20exposing,4%3A13ff%3B%202%20Tim.) [adjusted slightly]:

> - *Biblical exposition simply means exposing hearers to the meaning of the text of scripture (both its content and intent, in an exact and
>   exhaustive manner) and then applying it to the hearts and lives of the
>   hearers.*

Though neither is incorrect in your example, the instantiation (using 'an exposition') variant to mirror 'a story' is preferable. Compare 'It's only a simple tale, but I already love the story.'

Answer (score 0):

As for making the sentence "sound more interesting", per your comment, you need to have it make sense first, and your sentence doesn't quite make sense:  **already** in the second clause would require some reference to you being not very far along in the story in the first clause. However, neither "It's only exposition" or "It's only *an* exposition" has that meaning.

On the other hand, "It's only *the* exposition" could have the meaning of you not being far along, if "exposition" had the meaning "the beginning of a story" but it typically is used in that way only with *musical* forms.

> It's only the exposition but I already love this sonata.

"It" requires context to have clear meaning when there is no antecedent. Otherwise you'd be expecting the listener  either to deduce or intuit what you were talking about. If you were listening to the piece with someone, you could make the remark above. Or if you were composing the sonata, and were speaking with someone who knew you had not gotten very far into the composition, you could say it.

So, just use the phrase "It's only the beginning" and you'll be golden:

> It's only the beginning, but I already love the story.

That sentence would be interesting because it's an expression of how you feel about the story even though you're not very far along. No need to use a word in an unusual or clever way to make the statement interesting.

GRAMMAR: Among its many uses, the definite article is used to refer to things only one of which is typically encountered in a given context:

> I knocked on *the* front door.
>
> Things are going well, but of course it's *the* honeymoon phase. Time will tell.
>
> Could you please see that *the* CEO gets this message?
>
> [It's only *the* beginning](https://youtu.be/7yXIeQHEcx4?t=131) ...

Comment: Thank you for you clarification. But I still have a question: why can't I use the word "exposition", when I refer to the beginning of a story? This term is widely used in the literature field.

"The exposition of a story is the first paragraph or paragraphs in which the characters, setting (time and place), and basic information is introduced"

From my point of view, the word fits into the sentence well.

Comment: Of course, I can rewrite if it's required.

"These chapters are only the exposition, but I already love the story."

It's not really about "making the sentence more interesting". I just want to avoid any tautology in my writing. (I've already used the word "beginning" in another sentence.)

Comment: I don't think **the exposition** is widely used at all with short fiction or novels to refer to the opening pages or chapters of the work.  I haven't seen it used that way at any rate. But if you do happen to find the phrase used in that manner in a number of lit-crit *books* (not just on one site the internet) then you could use it, but be advised that it would be a technical lit-crit term that doesn't comport very well with "I already love the story".